# window.print() is avoiding a large page partially

Tags: javascript, css

```
<fieldset class="first">
<legend>First Part</legend>
--various controls like label/textbox/radio/checkbox....
```

> This is a small part, which can be adjusted within half of an A4 size
>   page.

```
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="second">
<legend>Second Part</legend>
--various controls like label/textbox/radio/checkbox....
```

> THis is a very large part, which should take two A4 size page

```
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="third">
<legend>Third Part</legend>
--various controls like label/textbox/radio/checkbox....
</fieldset>
```

This is the general structure of an HTML page.

When I try to print the whole page with `window.print()` command, First fieldset takes a whole page. the half of the lower portion of the page remain blank.

Second page shows the second fieldset but as it is larger to fit in one page, it doesn't extend to next page. Instead, the remaining controls are lost.

Then the Third page shows the third fieldset.

Everything is fine except the second page. How could I preview all controls of the second fieldset. If it breaks into two page that will be no problem.

I am trying to use `@media print{}` and trying to find out to solve this problem. But after a lot of googling, no solution is found yet.

If the question is not so clear, please ask to clearify.

**EDIT 1:**

```
@media print {

div {
    page-break-before:auto;
}
```

}

will it work for all div? I am defining it in gloabal.css. willit be ok?

One more thing, i have found that, the problem is in Firefox only. in Chrome & IE, it works fine. Any solution for firefox?

Comment: can you use CSS's page-break-before to manually paginate?

Comment: I have added an edition of the question. please check it @dandavis

Comment: you would use that more like, fieldset{page-break-after:always;} to put each fieldset on it's own page, which is what i think you're asking for...

Comment: fieldset cannot be used here. cause, in my first fieldset there are lots of inner fieldsets. I could not figure out a common pattern to set a pagebreak. It will only be possible if I can set `page-break-after: 20 controls(assuming)'. OR like page break if the control is overloaded in the page.